# Apache ignoring ServerName and server alias

Tags: apache

I have a site configured on my Apache server, the config for this is:

```
<VirtualHost wessex.ttltesting.co.uk:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/wessexbiomass.co.uk/www/htdocs"
ServerName wessex.ttltesting.co.uk
<Directory "/home/wessexbiomass.co.uk/www/htdocs">
allow from all
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I browse to the site on wessex.ttltesting.co.uk I am seeing my default virtual host not the one specified above?

Thanks!

Comment: I have fixed this now, the working configuration was:

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/wessexbiomass.co.uk/www/htdocs"
ServerName wessex.ttltesting.co.uk
<Directory "/home/wessexbiomass.co.uk/www/htdocs">
allow from all
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>